# how count the number of days even if my browser closed

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display an HTML buttton every 5 days because in my project an user can do  a recall after 5 days. 
my problem is that when i close my browser the counter will count to zeros again
i used setInterval to count the time

```
<script>
function fn(){
            document.getElementById("btn").style.display='block';
}       
 var x=5*24*60*60*1000 //number of days
 setInterval(fn,x);
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="save" method="post">

<label>if you do not see an add button that you do not have more than 5 days</label>
<input id="btn" type="submit" style="display: none;" value="Add Customer"/>

</form>
</body>
```

thank you

Comment: this can only be done on server side. Not in browser like you have done. Look at server side language to do what you want.

Comment: Well you’d obviously have to specify a start point somewhere, instead of going with 5 days from whatever time it is now ... But you also got to be aware that this is not going to actually stop anyone from sending such a request to your server to begin with. If you want this to be safe from any manipulation, then you have to perform the necessary checks on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I hope,It may be possible using cookie.on button press set cookie and expire time set to 5 days.

Answer (score 0):

you can record the current time in localStorage after displaying the HTML buttton,and every times when user open this page,get current time and compare with the last time you have recorded